# POI Missing method after upgrade

Tags: openxml

`when I upgrade  'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4' to  'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3',some method cannot find

my dependencies:

```
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1'
```

when Ichange dependencies ,it is right

```
//    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
//    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
//    implementation 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4'
//    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0
```

Comment: sorry,Methods as below CTShd cTShd = pr.getShd(); toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);CTFonts fonts = rpr.isSetRFonts() ? rpr.getRFonts() : rpr.addNewRFonts();rpr.getSzCs().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(v));

Comment: please update your question to post your codes. Difficult to read codes in comments.